# UglifyJS Maven aggregate

Tags: uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'd like to aggregate all minified JS files using the UglifyJS maven plugin, but there is no documentation on doing so and the plugin code doesn't mention anything about aggregation.
Is it the case that the plugin doesn't support aggregation?